# ColorPicker in ContentDialog in WinUI3 does not show spectrum always

Tags: winui-3

For a project in WinUI3, I am inserting ColorPicker in a StackPanel to be shown under ContentDialoag progmatically.

My code

```
            StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
            stack.Children.Clear();
            stack.Spacing = 5.0;

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.PlaceholderText = "Enter Team name";

            ComboBox country = new ComboBox();
            country.ItemsSource = CountryList;
            country.PlaceholderText = "Select Country";

            ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
            colorPicker.IsColorSpectrumVisible = true;
            colorPicker.IsAlphaEnabled= true;
            colorPicker.IsAlphaSliderVisible= true;

            stack.Children.Add(textBox);
            stack.Children.Add(country);
            stack.Children.Add(colorPicker);

            ContentDialog newTeam = new ContentDialog()
            {
                Title = "Create New Team",
                Content = stack,
                PrimaryButtonText = "Create",
                CloseButtonText = "Cancel"
            };

            newTeam.XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot;
            var result = await getDialogResult(newTeam);
//And so on, the ContentDialog is working fine
```

My ColorPicker randomly shows the color spectrum sometimes, other wise just remains empty with White color.

On my lucky day

[image]

On my unlucky day

[image]

I tried changing permutation and combination for various attributes given in WinUi3 App in MS Store.

```
<ColorPicker
      ColorSpectrumShape="Box"
      IsMoreButtonVisible="False"
      IsColorSliderVisible="True"
      IsColorChannelTextInputVisible="True"
      IsHexInputVisible="True"
      IsAlphaEnabled="False"
      IsAlphaSliderVisible="True"
      IsAlphaTextInputVisible="True" />
</ColorPicker>
```

But result is the same, it shows spectrum sometimes and sometimes doesnt. Any idea where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce you issue. It might be a bug. I guess using the `Loaded` event could be a workaround.

```cs
ContentDialog newTeam = new ContentDialog()
{
    Title = "Create New Team",
    //Content = colorPicker,
    PrimaryButtonText = "Create",
    CloseButtonText = "Cancel"
};

newTeam.XamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot;
newTeam.Loaded += NewTeam_Loaded;
var result = await newTeam.ShowAsync();
```

```cs
private void NewTeam_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stack = new StackPanel();
    stack.Children.Clear();
    stack.Spacing = 5.0;

    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.PlaceholderText = "Enter Team name";

    ComboBox country = new ComboBox();
    country.ItemsSource = CountryList;
    country.PlaceholderText = "Select Country";

    ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
    colorPicker.IsColorSpectrumVisible = true;
    colorPicker.IsAlphaEnabled = true;
    colorPicker.IsAlphaSliderVisible = true;
    colorPicker.Color = Colors.HotPink;

    stack.Children.Add(textBox);
    stack.Children.Add(country);
    stack.Children.Add(colorPicker);

    if (sender is ContentDialog contentDialog)
    {
        contentDialog.Content = stack;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the above, but did not work. Also my sender is a Button so I did  if(sender is Button button){ Debug.WriteLine("Button content reached");newTeam.Content = stack;}, it is reaching the condition but result remains the same.

Comment: My answer uses ``ContentDialog``'s ``Loaded`` event, so the sender is ``ContentDialog``. I acutally created a sample app and it works.

Comment: It was my fault, I had missed newTeam.Loaded += NewTeam_Loaded; on the top part...as again Thank you so much !